# Laravel project: force webpack to ignore some files

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

I'm building an application in Laravel 5.4 and Vue.js. Since I already have most of the components already created in another project I have imported that project as a git submodule in my Laravel application.
The problem is that when I run the command

```
npm run dev
```

I this error:

```
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
```

After some debugging I found out that the problem was that the project that I have imported as git submodules, containing my components, has some hidden configuration files like .env, .babelrc that trigger that error. If I remove them the compilation goes fine and I can use my component.

The problem is that I can't remove those files from the project the ideal approach it will be ignoring those kind of files in the webpack configuration of Laravel:

```
  mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
      .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

How can I achieve this? More over shouldn't Webpack compile only what is needed?
For example if I import one single component from my library I expect webpack to compile just that component, not everything else...

Comment: Post your `resources/assets/js/app.js` file and the full `webpack.mix.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing this:

```
mix.copy('node_modules/foo/bar.css', 'public/css/bar.css');
```

That way before bundling the js files I move all my components from the library to the assets/js/components folder in the laravel project and the compilation works fine!